# How to change permission of neo4j apoc function?

Tags: neo4j

I just installed Neo4j on Ubuntu and downloaded apoc.jar and put into the plugin folder.When i run `call apoc.help('search')` in Neo4j terminal it's show all apoc function list but in many function writes permission is false.Can anyone tell me how to change permission of those function in ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is add any of below settings to neo4j.conf file.

```
apoc.trigger.enabled=true
apoc.import.file.enabled=true
apoc.export.file.enabled=true
```

You can find more options in [docs](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_configuration_options).